# Spark SQL: unresolved attributes

Tags: apache-spark-sql

I receive the error below when I try to read count on sql results:

Error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.errors.package$TreeNodeException: Unresolved attributes
```

Here is the code I am using:

```
val results= sqlContext.sql("select * from  tablename")
results.collect().foreach(println)
```

I am using Spark 1.1.0 and running the program locally.

Answer (score 0):

Possible reasons why you getting the exception:

1. If you try querying the sqlContext without registering the RDD as a table.

   `sqlContext.registerTempTable("testQuery")`
2. SparkSQL is case sensitive. Make sure `tablename` matches the case you defined in your Cassandra.
3. Make sure the tablename` exist.

Answer (score 0):

This issue can occur in Spark 1.1 if you are querying a partitioned hive table that has had a column added with the alter table command.  Even though the table schema knows about the new column, any data partitions created before the new column was added do not have the table in their partition schema.

Select * will pull a list of columns from the table schema but when it processes the older data partition, since the column does not exist in the partition schema, spark will not find the column and thus will throw this unresolved attribute error.

If this is the issue you are facing then instead of using select *, specify a explicit list of column names.  This is only a partial solution, though, because if you explicitly list a column name that doesn't exist in an older partition then you'll still get the error.